# Setting up a multi monitor office status display

Tags: ubuntu, display, monitoring, multiplexing

My office has a number of identical monitors laying around that will be trashed unless I can think of something to do with them. I was thinking of getting 2 of [these](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16814195083&cm_re=FirePro_2450_PCIe-_-14-195-083-_-Product) and putting them in an extra box. Are these graphics cards a good choice?

After the graphics cards, what software would be good to monitor several webpages/programs, each on their own screen?

Any tips from someone who has built an office status display? This whole setup will likely be running ubuntu.

Comment: As a side question: What kind of interface is this http://www.newegg.com/Product/ImageGallery.aspx?CurImage=14-195-083-S03&ISList=14-195-083-S01%2c14-195-083-S02%2c14-195-083-S03%2c14-195-083-S04%2c14-195-083-S05&S7ImageFlag=1&Item=N82E16814195083&Depa=0&WaterMark=1&Description=ATI%20100-505531%20FirePro%202450%20512MB%20GDDR3%20PCI%20Express%202.0%20x16%20%26%20x1%20Lane%20Low%20Profile%20Multi-View%20Workstation%20Graphics%20Accelerator? That looks almost like SCSI

Comment: In pictures, it looks like it is some weird cable that transforms the output to 4 DVI ports

Answer (score 1):

If its one website per screen, you should be able to just use your OS to configure a multi-monitor set up, and run the web browsers and apps, one per screen. Shouldn't need any fancy software.

Answer (score 0):

A buddy of mines uses [xmonad](http://xmonad.org/) to handle his screen real estate and really likes it